# Как решить проблемы таймаута для очередей Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Просто бесконечная проблема, отправляю джобы на выполнение в очередь, а после проверяю выполнились ли все задачи. Всё работает ок, но спустя час ошибка 500, обрабатываю примерно 30 тысяч строк. Пытался делать таймаут внутри класса каждой очереди, таймаут внутри .htaccess, через fastpanel, через сервер напрямую менять у php.ini и всё безрезультатно. Использую Laravel 5.4.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    $content = file_get_contents($file->getPathname());
    $array = explode("\r\n", $content);
    $cnt=0;
    foreach ($array as $el) {
        $cnt++;
        AsyncCheckerJob::dispatch($el,$cnt)->onQueue('async_jobs');
    }
     // Проверяем, завершились ли все задачи
    $allJobsFinished = true;
    do {
        $queueSize = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::size('async_jobs');
        if ($queueSize > 0) {
            $allJobsFinished = false;
            sleep(5); // Подождем некоторое время перед проверкой снова
        }
    } while (!$allJobsFinished);
```